# Chicken Genome what are the LGE 'chromosomes'?

Tags: chickens, ornithology, genomes

The chicken genome identifies two "LGE" sequences in the chicken genome.  Are these distinct chromosomes or some highly variable sequence from the genome that is put in a separate sequence? I'm thinking they are not really separate chromosomes.... It would be great to know a little bit about their biology.  the papers didn't seem to help me.

[image: chromosome images for chicken genome]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LG stands for "linkage group". It seems the Chicken Genome Sequence group ([Hillier et al., 2004](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v432/n7018/full/nature03154.html)) allocated several [linkage groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_group) (alleles or genes which tend to be inherited together) to the [microchromosomes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchromosome) (tiny chromosomes typical of birds and reptiles), in this case called "linkage group E64" and "linkage group E22....". There are a load more microchromosomes which are the ones numbered 28-31 and 33-38 which haven't yet had their sequences resolved ([Burt, 2007](http://ps.fass.org/content/86/7/1460.full)).

**References:**

- Burt, D.W. (2007) Emergence of the Chicken as a Model Organism: Implications for Agriculture and Biology. Poultry Science. 86 (7), 1460 –1471. Available from:  [Accessed: 8 February 2012].
- Hillier, L.D.W., Miller, W., Birney, E., Warren, W., Hardison, R.C., Ponting, C.P., Bork, P., Burt, D.W., Groenen, M.A.M. & Delany, M.E. (2004) Sequence and comparative analysis of the chicken genome provide unique perspectives on vertebrate evolution. Nature. 432 (7018), 695–716.

Comment: So this makes them a little bit like the 'random' chromosomes in the human builds i guess.